# "quit" option for multiple window on Ubuntu Dock

Tags: ubuntu-dock

My Ubuntu after gnome tweaks application theme modification does not allow quit option for individual closure in several open windows for the same program on Dock Bar. I changed Adwaita (default) by Radiance.  I would like to "re-activate" this option.

[image: personal-desktop-screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean by "several appearances changes"? What exactly have you done to cause those changes? Does quit button not appear even if you hover your cursor over the small window preview? Please **[edit]** your question and clarify.

Comment: I mean by "several appearances changes" by gnome tweaks application theme modification. I changed Adwaita (default) by Radiance. No, it doesn't. I hover the cursor and it does not appear at all. Just as the picture uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I made several application theme changes looking for possible solutions but the problem continues even with different themes choices. I decided first to select an specific application theme (Radiance). Second, I updated and upgraded my system. Lastly, I restarted my laptop and as a result the issue was solved.

Comment: Changing the application theme shouldn't have had any effect. You most likely just needed to do the "update system and restart" part.